# PopupWindow won't dismiss

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow declared at the class level:

```
private PopupWindow dialogScanBadge;
```

I create the window upon a user action:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_scan_badge, viewGroup);  
dialogScanBadge = new PopupWindow(layout);
```

and add it to the current ViewGroup.  I only want to display the pop up for 7 seconds and then have it removed:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        Intent intent = new Intent(Strings.ACTION_PROCESS_SCAN_RESULTS);
        sendBroadcast(intent);                  
    }
}, 7000);
```

which calls (on UI thread):

```
dialogScanBadge.dismiss();
```

But the pop up remains displayed.  There are no errors encountered and I have confirmed that the line `dialogScanBadge.dismiss();` is executed.

I have seen the numerous SO posts that all have this solution.  But, this is not working.

I have also tried without success:

```
viewGroup.removeView(dialogScanBadge.getContentView());
```

Please advise

Comment: Try to run dismiss on UIThread maybe?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari  It is, that's why I call it with an Intent.

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(); can help i think

Comment: can i see the code where it is dismissed?